# PrimeFaces Dock icon issue

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces

I am using the Primefaces Doc. When it displays, it displays like so:

[image]

The icons are on top of each other and not spread out in the doc like normal. I tried messing with the css elements on the page but could not find one that is causing this.

Does anyone have any idea on why this might be or if it is indeed css (or the element) that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was because I added jQuery explicitly, and Primefaces adds it on its own. If you do this, you will run into weird css issues.